# Как проверить существует ли лист в Excel-файле? (Apache POI)

Tags: java, android-studio, apache, excel, apache-poi

В операторе If я проверяю,существует ли Excel-файл, чтобы потом открыть его и выполнить ряд действий но кроме проверки существования самого файла как я могу сразу добавить проверку на существование в этом файле листа(sheet) под определенным индексом или названием.Существующий код привожу ниже:

```
File b = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/plik.xls");
                if (b.exists()) {  
                    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/plik.xls");
                    try {
                        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);.....
```

Comment: Перебрать коллекцию листов книги и сравнить имя каждого листа с требуемым.

Comment: Обработать любое обращение к листу. Если ошибка - нет такого

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Add_New_Sheet()
    Dim wsSh As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsSh = Sheets("Новый лист")
    If wsSh Is Nothing Then Sheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Новый лист"
    'здесь можно либо активировать лист, либо производить еще какие действия
    'wsSh.Activate
End Sub
```

Если предполагается использовать такую проверку более одного раза в коде, то имеет смысл вынести проверку в отдельную функцию

```
Function Sh_Exist(wb As Workbook, sName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wsSh As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsSh = wb.Sheets(sName)
    Sh_Exist = Not wsSh Is Nothing
End Function
```

Источник: [Excel - vba](https://www.excel-vba.ru/chto-umeet-excel/kak-uznat-sushhestvuet-li-list-v-knige/)

Вам лишь надо узнать как вызвать макрос на вашем ЯП.(это не сложно)